# Read a file into Pandas dataframe where rows are grouped by date

Tags: python, pandas

File is a CSV-like format in which rows are grouped by date, and date information is omitted from rows containing information other than date. Such formats can be recognized by having a "/" character in their header line.

```
start_date / lat,lon,tmax
1979-01-01
27,261,10.522
27,262,11.772
28,261,9.205
1979-01-02
27,261,10.139
27,262,10.913
28,261,8.982
```

Currently using below code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(fileName, delimiter = ',')
```

which gives the ouput

```
    start_date / lat    lon tmax
0   1979-01-01  NaN NaN
1   27  261.0   10.522
2   27  262.0   11.772
3   28  261.0   9.205
4   1979-01-02  NaN NaN
5   27  261.0   10.139
6   27  262.0   10.913
7   28  261.0   8.982
```

Desired Output.

```
    start_date    lat    lon    tmax
0   1979-01-01    27    261.0   10.522
1   1979-01-01    27    262.0   11.772
2   1979-01-01    28    261.0   9.205
3   1979-01-02    27    261.0   10.139
4   1979-01-02    27    262.0   10.913
5   1979-01-02    28    261.0   8.982
```

How to read such a file into pandas dataframe and get the desired output?

Comment: post a fragment with more than one section (few groups) to make it testable

Comment: done. check now.

Comment: please also add the expected/desired output

Comment: I don't think you can load it directly into the way that you want, but if you are ok with loading and doing some processing to the data frame, you should be able to get your desired output

Comment: @ArihantJain, you may also apply shift techniques in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sensing is that because of the nature of your data, pandas might not have a direct way to load the data to your desired outcome. This is how I would approach your situation if it was me.

1. I would load in the file as you have done.
2. Rename the columns to suit your final table outcome.
3. use pd.to_datetime function to keep the dates and clean out all the non-dates data. This will be your eventual date column.
4. Use the fillna method to fill all the missing values on the date.

Attached is the code that I wrote based on my logic above.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt')
df['lat'] = df['start_date / lat']
df.columns = ['start_date', 'lon', 'tmax', 'lat']
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], errors='coerce')
df['start_date'] = df['start_date'].fillna(method='ffill')
df[df['lon'].notnull()]
```

I copied your data and create test.txt locally to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

With flexible *shifting*:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+/\s+|,', skipinitialspace=True)
df = df.apply(lambda s: s.shift(1), 1).apply(lambda s: s.shift(-1) if pd.isna(s[-1]) else s, 1)
df['start_date'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The resulting `df`:

```
   start_date lat    lon    tmax
0  1979-01-01  27  261.0  10.522
1  1979-01-01  27  262.0  11.772
2  1979-01-01  28  261.0   9.205
3  1979-01-02  27  261.0  10.139
4  1979-01-02  27  262.0  10.913
5  1979-01-02  28  261.0   8.982
```

[pandas.Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.Series.shift)